# VBA Copying File; surpress "file already exists" and determine if successful?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that I am using to copy a folder from my local PC to a network shared drive (to backup).  I have two questions around my code.  First, when the code runs, it acts just like a copy/paste in Windows in that if the files already exist, it asks me if I want to overwrite them.  I do want to overwrite them, as I am running the code every day, so how do I suppress this?

Second, I would like to be able to determine if the copy/paste happened successfully.  Is there a way to do this?

I was using the VBA copy functionality, but it showed no progress bar, so I was afraid I would open Outlook at some point and mess up the file copy.
Anyways, here is my code.

```
Private Sub Main()

    'unrelated code

    If Len(Dir("\\aubinsFS01\E9786046$\")) <> 0 Then
        If Len(Dir("C:\Users\E9786046\Documents\Outlook Files\")) <> 0 Then

                'Taken from multiple examples
                'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/238407-progress-bar-copying-file.html

                Dim FromPath As Variant
                Dim ToPath As Variant

                FromPath = "C:\Users\E9786046\Documents\Outlook Files\"  '<< Change
                ToPath = "\\aubinsFS01\E9786046$\Personal Folder Backup"    '<< Change

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))       'Delay to allow Outlook to close

                Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                '//The source Folder to CopyFrom:
                Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FromPath)

                '//The source Folder to CopyTo:
                objFolder.CopyHere ToPath, &H0&

                Set objShell = Nothing
                Set objFolder = Nothing

                MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath
        Else
            MsgBox "Personal folder location not found.  Please check your personal folder."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Network location not available.  Check your shared drives for connection."
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Close
    End

End Sub
```

Comment: IIRC, your options are wrong - it should be `objFolder.CopyHere ToPath, &H10&`

Comment: @Rory Nevermind, this did fix the issue.  Orgininal:  Care to elaborate?  The code works as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @rory above is correct; changing from `objFolder.CopyHere ToPath, &H0&` to `objFolder.CopyHere ToPath, &1H0&` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can supress warnings with

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Make sure to turn it back on (i.e. `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`) after you overwrote your file.

Comment: It still asks me whether or not I want to overwrite the folder and the files.