# How to copy all files from one folder to another - no prompt window

Tags: excel, vba

I got macro

```
   Dim MyFile2 As String
   Dim myPath2 As String, myPath3 As String

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True         
   Application.EnableEvents = True          
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
   myPath2 = fPathDone
   myPath3 = fpath

   MyFile2 = Dir(myPath2 & "*.*")
   Do While MyFile2 <> ""
        FileCopy myPath2 & MyFile2, myPath3 & MyFile2
        MyFile2 = Dir
   Loop
```

Macro creates copy of all excel files from source fPathDone to fpath. It works but I do not why I do not get alert that asks me if I want to overwrite file if file already exists in fpath location. What can i change in the code?

Regards,
Jambojet

Comment: It's not clear if you _do_ or _do not_ want the warning.   [This Q&A can do both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37392549/445425)

Comment: Check if the destination file exists and if so, delete it.  `If Dir(myPath3 & MyFile2)<>"" Then Kill myPath3 & MyFile2`

Comment: i want to have warning. Now i do not have it. Thank you for your answers.